# execute custom code when user logs on into intranet

Tags: .net, windows, sharepoint

is there a way to run my code (what ever) when a user logs on into a Intranet?

It is a SharePoint farm and I want to create my site in the background for the user when he logs in into the intranet by logging in his/her computer).

thanks

Comment: From the comments below I understand the question has nothing to do with SharePoint.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can take a look to Global.asax => there is SessionStart() where you can do that kind of jobs.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2027ewzw.aspx

Comment: Thanks ykatchou, but sessionStarts() method runs when you browse to the inranet, what i wanted is when you log on the computer which is added to intranet (before you browse)

Comment: Maybe you can configure that in Active Directory.

Comment: Do you mean exactly? is it possible to run custom code in AD?

Comment: Perhaps, i don't know :s contact your administrator, he probably know a way to do that. You can also set an app to launch in the startup menus...

Answer (score 0):

There's a way, but I'm not sure how ethical it is, as it's going little bit into domain of hacking. You can do kind of code executions using iframes as, most like (as you are using SharePoint) users are also using Internet Explorer. Or you can google little bit about thinks like this one:

http://thehackernews.com/2012/02/dangerous-ie-browser-vulnerabilities.html

But, I said again, be careful if that's really something what you want.

Comment: thank you,
I am not sure I have formulate my question well. 
What I want to do is when you log on a computer which is in a intranet before doing anything else, I want my code be executed (before you open IE).

Comment: http://www.petri.co.il/setting-up-logon-script-through-active-directory-users-computers-windows-server-2008.htm I think this is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean when a user logs in to his computer = to his Windows? You can create a [logon script](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc758918%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) that triggers a service (web service, e.g.) or executes remotely a command (PowerShell, e.g.) on the SharePoint server. In that command/service you can check the existence of My Site and create it.

--- Ferda